# Can OllyDbg trace a launched exe?

Tags: debugging, exe, executable, trace, ollydbg

If my product, MyApp.exe, is being debugged by OllyDbg (or any other debugger really), but the exe  launches another one (such as MakeSerial.exe); will OllyDbg start debugging the newly-launched exe too? Or does it just trace MyApp.exe only? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, OllyDbg will not automatically debug child processes.

You could however look for the [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call that launches the child process and edit it's parameter `dwCreationFlags` in include the flag [`CREATE_SUSPENDED
(0x00000004)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then you can either detach from the parent process or open a new instance of OllyDbg to attach to the child process and resume/debug it.

Comment: Thanks guys; both answers are valid and show a way to do it, so I don't know who to give the tick (I'm new here)... but I assume to the first reply. Done.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**, the newest version of ***[OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html)*** has an option to automatically debug child processes.

[image]

Comment: Question, if the process being created is with the the flag CREATE_SUSPENDED (0x00000004), OllyDbg 2 does not execute automatically, will it wait until ResumeThread is executed?

Answer (score 3):

and with the older ollydbg (version 1.10 ) goto `openrce.org` and download the

```
Modified commandline plugin by anonymouse
```

hit `alt+f1` and type `childdbg 1` (log window should show debugging of child window enbaled)

now ollydbg 1.10 will also be able to catch the child process